# SvelteKit re-transition on every form action

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have a simple SvelteKit form as follows:

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import { fly } from 'svelte/transition';
    import { enhance } from '$app/forms';
    import type { ActionData } from './$types';

    export let form: ActionData;
</script>

<form method="POST" action="?/login" use:enhance>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="student@example.edu" />
    <button>Register</button>
</form>

{#if form === 'EMAIL_SENT'}
    <p>We sent a magic login link to your email!</p>
{:else if form === 'EMAIL_INVALID'}
    <p>Please enter a valid email.</p>
{/if}
```

The problem is that if the user submits an invalid email twice, nothing on the page will change the second time to indicate that their second attempt was still invalid. I tried adding a transition directive to animate the feedback text like so:

```html
...
<p transition:fade>We sent a magic login link to your email!</p>
<p transition:fade>Please enter a valid email.</p>
...
```

However, this transition only runs if the form action results in a state change. If the user submits an invalid and then a valid email, the fade will occur twice, but if they submit an invalid email twice, the fade only occurs once. How can I instruct SvelteKit to run the transition on every form action no matter if there is a state change?

Answer (score 1):

You could clear the form value on submit:

```html
<form use:enhance={() => { form = null }} ...>
```

You might also want to switch the transition to just `in:fade`, otherwise if the response is very fast, you will not notice anything.

Comment: Just tried this, all it did was clear out the feedback text on the second submission?

Comment: If the second submission was invalid the server should send another response that gets set to `form` which then should trigger a fade in. If this does not work, something else is wrong.